# Using Dapper and Sqlite how do I get a newly inserted row id

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I found that the following sqlite will get me the inserted id in Dapper, however, is this safe in concurrent scenarios?

```
string sql = @"
    insert into MyTable values (null, @name);  
    select last_insert_rowid();";
```

Comment: select last_insert_rowid(); is not table specific. If you are not the only one using that database, or you yourself access it concurrently, this will work only by accident. So the overall answer is "NO".

Answer (score 0):

You asked "... is this safe in concurrent scenarios?" and the simple answer is "NO".

You can do it, however, to get the id by doing a "select id where ***specify values for some primary key or UNIQUE fields***"